# In Visual Studio 2013, is there a way to access classes in a DLL that is referenced within an included project DLL?

Tags: dll

For Example, if I include a reference to Test1.DLL in my project and Test1.DLL references Test2.DLL is there a way I can access logic within Test2.DLL in my project without adding a reference to it directly in my project?

Answer (score 0):

Yes u can do. Your project contains Test1.dll.

Ex: Your Project
        reference->Test1.dll

Test1.dll refers to Test2.dll,Test3.dll,...
If any changes in Test2.dll,Test3.dll it will reflects the Your project. When ever Your building the project.

Regards,
Sekhar

Comment: I know that but for instance if I have a class called Test2 in the Test2.DLL then how do I create an instance of that class without specifically including a reference to Test2.DLL in my project.  I haven't found a way to reach it just going through Test1.DLL.